What was the reason for not personifying God's spirit in NABRE's translation of John 14:17?
Some languages, such as Spanish or French have gendered nouns, and so have words corresponding to "he" and "she", but not to "it".
For instance, "the fork" and "the knife" would each be referenced by "it" in English, but in French "la fourchette" and "le couteau" would be referenced by "elle" and "il", the equivalents of "she" and "he".
Translators must make the (obvious) choice to use "it" in this case.
Similarly in Greek, whenever a gendered pronoun is translated into English one must choose between "he" and "it", or between "she" and "it".
Consider John 14:
King James Version:

16 And I will pray the Father, and he shall give you another Comforter, that he may abide with you for ever;
17 Even the Spirit of truth; whom the world cannot receive, because it seeth him not, neither knoweth him: but ye know him; for he dwelleth with you, and shall be in you.
26 But the Comforter, which is the Holy Ghost, whom the Father will send in my name, he shall teach you all things, and bring all things to your remembrance, whatsoever I have said unto you.

New American Bible (Revised Edition):

16 And I will ask the Father, and he will give you another Advocate to be with you always,
17 the Spirit of truth, which the world cannot accept, because it neither sees nor knows it.
But you know it, because it remains with you, and will be in you.
26 The Advocate, the holy Spirit that the Father will send in my name — he will teach you everything and remind you of all that [I] told you.

Both versions personify God's holy spirit as "he" in verse 26 (and most (all?) other scripture), but for verse 17 specifically, one version uses "he" while the other uses "it".
Even within John, the spirit of truth is referred to as "he" in 15:26 and 16:13, so why was it inconsistently translated as "it" in 14:17?
Why did the NABRE's translators decide that "it" was more appropriate in this case?
Note: The question is not about whether it is correct to personify God's spirit (Trinitarian vs. non-Trinitarian doctrines), but about this one specific verse.

Pneuma in Greek is neuter, a grammatical gender but not a personal gender. English never refers to a person as 'it'. (Except when a baby's appearance  cannot be determined as to gender and 'it' is, idiomatically, appropriate.) It seems eccentric for any translation to refer to the Holy Spirit himself as 'it'. But an influence he gives can be (as an influence within the recipient) referred to as 'it'. The NABRE seems to have erred in this particular verse, I would suggest myself. But who can peer into their motives ?

In addition to the grammar explained in the answers Jesus identifies the Spirit of Truth as allos parakletos. Allos is another of the same type (heteros would be another of a different type). So the parakletos will be like Jesus and should be identified accordingly. "It" would convey heteros; "he" conveys allos.

The reasons for this are entirely grammatical and John 14; John's use of pronouns referring to the Holy Spirit reflect the antecedent gender.  Let me be more specific.
Before launching into all these details, let me first remind ourselves of two grammatical facts:

Πνεῦμα (Pneuma = "Spirit") is grammatically neuter
Ἅγιον (Hargion = "Holy") is grammatically neuter
ἀληθείας (aletheias = "truth") is grammatically feminine
Παράκλητος (Parakletos = "Advocate") is grammatically masculine

Now, let me tabulate, in John 14, how John uses the pronouns:

V16: "He"/"It" does not exist in the Greek so the question is moot
V17: "whom" is neuter because the antecedent is "Spirit"; The two third person pronouns, referring to "Spirit" are neuter
V26: "whom" refers to "Spirit" and thus is neuter"; "He" refers to "Advocate" and thus is masculine

Here is my literal translation of V26:

However, the Advocate, the Holy Spirit, whom [N] the Father will
send in My Name, He [M] will teach you all [things] and will bring
to your remembrance all that I have said to you.

Notice that withing the one sentence, the Holy Spirit/Advocate is referred to with BOTH neuter and masculine pronouns depending on the antecedent.
Now, because, English does not have grammatical gender for most nouns, this becomes confusing and so the translators must decide to make things more consistent.  Most modern versions choose to translate using masculine pronouns for the Holy Spirit; the NASB and the ESV choose to rigidly (and at times confusingly) translate the gender of the Greek pronouns which makes their antecedent in English sometimes tricky to follow.

Two thoughts. 1) It may be worth mentioning, for anyone not familiar with the grammar, why v16 doesn’t have “he/she/it” in the Greek. It’s because Greek verbs can appear without pronouns, far more freely than in English, and with more clues as to who/what the subject is—but not perfect information. In v16, the verb “to be [with]” is in the form that’s correct for “he/she/it” (but not “they”, “we”, or “you”), so one of those is implied.


I’m reminded of Mark Twain’s The Awful German Language, which also looks at an English speaker’s confusion when dealing with a language with grammatical gender, and which doesn’t always match the semantic gender, nor even the grammatical gender of a different word used for the same being! “Ah the poor Fishwife, it is stuck fast in the Mire… It opens its Mouth to cry for Help; but if any Sound comes out of him, alas he is drowned by the raging of the Storm.”


Let's go to the horse's mouth to start. Here is how the NABRE itself answers the question in its footnote i for this chapter:

While it has been customary to use masculine personal pronouns in
English for the Advocate, the Greek word for “spirit” is neuter, and
the Greek text and manuscript variants fluctuate between masculine and
neuter pronouns.

Regarding @Betho's statement that "One pivotal aspect of the NABRE's translation philosophy is its commitment to gender-neutral language," this is a bit unfair. It has opted for a gender-neutral approach in this particular case but it has a solid basis for this, as explained above. Compare its handling of gender-inclusivity with the NIV, for example, which routinely substitutes "brothers and sisters" when the text says "brothers." NIV's New Testament uses the term "brothers and sisters" 124 times while the NABRE uses it only twice, reflecting a healthy respect for the text itself as opposed to an overriding commitment to gender neutrality.
That said, it is certainly true that the NABRE has raised eyebrows because of its inclusive language. One Catholic critic complains:

With the NABRE, the U.S. Bishops have used inclusive language more
extensively than ever before. Masculine references are obscured or
neutered. But of course all feminine references are retained.

Nevertheless, in this particular case, the editors of the NABRE have explained their reasons adequately. "Pneuma" is neuter in gender, and there are textual traditions which support both "it" and "he."

Even within John, the spirit of truth is referred to as "he" in 15:26 and 16:13, so the question is why was it inconsistently translated as "it" in 14:17?

@RayButterworth I can only report what the NABRE editors wrote. I do not pass judgment on their motivation but I do say they explain themselves adequately.

If gender sensitivity were the reason, wouldn't they have chosen ‘they/them’ rather than ‘it’?  (After all, ‘they’ has been used as a gender-neutral singular pronoun for many centuries, so would have seemed natural even back in 1986 when the NABRE NT was released.)

John 14:17
τὸ Πνεῦμα τῆς ἀληθείας, ὃ ὁ κόσμος οὐ δύναται λαβεῖν, ὅτι οὐ θεωρεῖ αὐτὸ οὐδὲ γινώσκει· ὑμεῖς γινώσκετε αὐτό, ὅτι παρ’ ὑμῖν μένει καὶ ἐν ὑμῖν ἔσται.

John 14:26
ὁ δὲ Παράκλητος, τὸ Πνεῦμα τὸ Ἅγιον ὃ πέμψει ὁ Πατὴρ ἐν τῷ ὀνόματί μου, ἐκεῖνος ὑμᾶς διδάξει πάντα καὶ ὑπομνήσει ὑμᾶς πάντα ἃ εἶπον ὑμῖν ἐγώ.

It looks like in both passages NABRE have carried the Greek's grammatical gender across into the English translation.
John 14:26 is different from John 14:17 because here the subject isn't the (neuter) Spirit but the (masculine) Advocate that is the Spirit.
I suppose that might contribute to their policy of using gender-neutral language (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_American_Bible_Revised_Edition#Gender-neutral_language) if
(1) it lets them turn all the grammatically-neuter things in Greek into gender-neutral things in English
(2) it might make it easier to see any more controversial changes, or mitigate their impact on the original text
The important thing (with He vs It) is that neither way of translating can be very successful when there is a fundamental grammatical difference between the two languages.
Greek's syntactic gender doesn't personify or de-personify as bluntly as English's bio-social gender. The spirit being neuter in Greek isn't a conscious decision by the language to make it a thing-without-sex, it's the cumulative result of its having been equally likely (over millions of usages by living speakers over hundreds of years) to be the subject or the object of the sentence. Greek's neuter gender isn't telling us what the spirit wears at the weekend - it's a syntactic flag warning the listener they're going to need to make a decision based on context.
